# Replace dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient in maven-pmd-plugin and maven-checkstyle-plugin

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-plugin, maven-checkstyle-plugin, dependency-exclusion

I do use `maven-pmd-plugin:3.15.0` and the `maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.1.2`.

Both do import transitively on an old version of the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.2`.

How can I configure each plugin to use the newest version of the httpclient (`org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13`)?

Edited regarding below comment why I need to replace the dependency:
My project (springboot 2.4.x application) uses `camel-http-starter` dependency which also transitively imports the 4.5.13 version and after calling `mvn clean install` or `verify|test|package`randomly I do get following exception

```
Exception in thread "ivy-httpclient-shutdown-handler" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$2
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.shutdown(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:413)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder$2.close(HttpClientBuilder.java:1244)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.close(InternalHttpClient.java:201)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.url.HttpClientHandler.close(HttpClientHandler.java:357)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.url.HttpClientHandler$1.run(HttpClientHandler.java:84)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$2
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 6 more
```

As I read in other forums [here](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-cube/issues/172#issuecomment-132761092)
old versions of the httpclient do not contain the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager as this has been introduced in 4.3.

The build does work fine. Its just this exception, which appears from time to time just right after the BUILD SUCCESS message.

My assumption is that maven has a flat classpath with every version of the httpclient and those time when it picks an old it cant find this class `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$2` and the exception is thrown.

Comment: Why would you like to replace the dependencies of the plugins?

Comment: @khmarbaise I edited my question. Thanks to all of you for your feedback and help!

Comment: Please show your pom file ...second `ivy-httpclient-shutdown-handler` this looks like you are using ivy? Looks not related to the plugins you have mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

In general take a look on the plugins page https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ which lists the most recent versions of plugins.

So for [maven-pmd-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/) there is a version 3.16.0 which I recommend to upgrade to.

Furthermore for the [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/) there is currently no newer version availble.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the `http-client` dependency from `maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.1.2`

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This works for me

Comment: Why does it work?